# Group array of objects by different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects structured as below:

```
const myArr = [
   { name: "John", surname: "Smith", age: 18},
   { name: "Steve", surname: "Jones", age: 23},
   { name: "Mark", surname: "Green", age: 45},
   { name: "Anne", surname: "Williams", age: 34}
]
```

And I would like to group it like so:

```
[
   {name: ["John", "Steve", "Mark", "Anne"]},
   {surname: ["Smith", "Jones", "Green", "Williams"]},
   {age: [18, 23, 45, 34]}
]
```

What's the best way? Tried with `reduce()` but no luck.

Comment: Hey, looks like it's duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know all objects have exactly the same keys, you can use Object.keys() function on the first element of the array, then iterate over the keys to create your objects

```
Object.keys(myArr[0]).map(key => {
    const obj = {}; // Probably a better way to do that
    obj[key] = myArr.map(item => item[key]);
    return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Nastier but shorter.

```js
Object.keys(myArr[0]).map(key => ({ [key]: myArr.map(item => item[key]) }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array, get all entries from the object and push to the array with the wanted key.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: "John", surname: "Smith", age: 18 }, { name: "Steve", surname: "Jones", age: 23 }, { name: "Mark", surname: "Green", age: 45 }, { name: "Anne", surname: "Williams", age: 34 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (r[k] ??= []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and build an object with keys and aggregate values in array. 
Now, create the array from above object entries.

```js
const process = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach((item) =>
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) =>
      (res[key] ??= []).push(value)
    )
  );
  return Object.entries(res).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
};

const myArr = [
  { name: "John", surname: "Smith", age: 18 },
  { name: "Steve", surname: "Jones", age: 23 },
  { name: "Mark", surname: "Green", age: 45 },
  { name: "Anne", surname: "Williams", age: 34 },
];

console.log(process(myArr));
```